# Displaying div in an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which displays testCount and pestCount on a button click. How could I alter this so that testCount and pestCount could be displayed in an alert box on button click.

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#button').click(function() { 
   $('#output').text(nCount + pCount);     
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI is your answer.  Specifically http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: This looks fantastic, do you know a way to make this box pop up on a button click instead of page load?

Comment: Spoke to soon, figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#button').click(function() { 
   alert(nCount + pCount);     
  });
});
```

Comment: This displays each count in a separate alert when it's displayed in a div it's just the one. Anyway to solve this

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, can you elaborate?